# Compile Vulkan witth FLTK

Tags: vulkan, fltk

I'm trying to build with vulkan using the Windowing stack called FLTK.
I am using this as my template: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Base_code

https://pastebin.com/qY2Rc9zc

The current code I have posted to pastebin compiles and runs?  There is no window when I run it

As I'm using FLTK you compile with this command: `fltk-config --compile ./HelloTriangle.cxx`

Also, no, I don't the gl triangle in the window. I just need **a** window to show right now.

The code below **does** make a blank window:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
//#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(800,600);

window->end();
window->show(argc, argv);
return Fl::run();
```

}

Yet, I want to set this up to work with Vulkan and I don't want to use glfw for my window.

Comment: Are you building this on Windows or Linux or Mac or something else

Comment: I'm building on Linux.